# Why aren't some plugin styles loading when I load a template?

Tags: plugin-development, templates

I'm using `template_redirect` to load custom template files based on the URL:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    if (is_singular('business'))
    {
        load_template(get_plugin_path() . 'templates/business.php');
    }
});
```

It works for the most part, but a few CSS files don't appear to be loading. Specifically, Elementor Pro's `frontend.min.css` file isn't loading even though some of its other files are. That messes up some of the styles on my site.

What causes this to happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the WordPress Codex, using [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) to load a different template is discouraged and can cause certain code to not be executed, which of course can result in strange bugs.

[`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) is the more appropriate solution. It loads a template file but without the behavior mentioned above.

```
add_action( 'template_include', function($original_template)
{
    if (is_singular('business'))
    {
        load_template(get_plugin_path() . 'templates/business.php');
    }

    return $original_template;
});
```